# UTF-8 & ISO-8859-2 Problem

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, iso

I've got a problem with html encoding. I work on PSPad. I set utf-8 as charset in my files and utf-8 as a file format and it look fine on localhost but doesn't on a server.
When i change file format to iso it works on a server but doesn't on localhost and when i close PSPad and reopen the file it totaly breaks some of the characters.
Do u have any solution? It so annoying! :)
thanks
K.

Comment: What meta tags are set on the page and what is the `Content-Type` HTTP header look like?

Comment: @Oded I use <meta charset="utf-8"/> (html5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the foreign server sends a charset declaration as well. What server software do you use? In Apache you could achieve it by adding a .htaccess file with the following content:

```
AddCharset utf-8 .html
```

Also make sure that you add a

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
```

declaration (HTML5) or a

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

To the HTML file header.

Edit: corrected typos

Comment: Thanks it did solve the problem. Apache default charset is iso so i cant change it because there is a lot of websites with iso charset. I not sure but i think this change would break old websites. htacces added to single folder solved the problem.